# Why is not the entire line read from a file used as search string with my batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

Can someone have a look at this mess please?

I have in the file `test.txt` a line with the search string `Coupon (%)`, but **FINDSTR** searches just for `Coupon`. I have tried another line with search string `Coupon frequency` in file `test.txt` which results in searching also just for `Coupon`.

This is the command line in the batch file:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /s /b C:\Users\me\Desktop\script\links\') do for /f %%t in ('type C:\Users\me\Desktop\script\test.txt') do for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /c:"%%t" %%f') do C:\Users\me\Desktop\script\links2.exe %%f %%a && echo %%t
```

How can I make this command line to use the entire line in file `test.txt` as entire search string as I would expect with the **FINDSTR** `/c:` switch please?

It works fine if I use the option `/g:` on searching the file `test.txt`. But I need the search results output to be in the order in which I specified the search strings in the file `test.txt` and `/g:` outputs all lines with any of the searched strings in line order of the searched file which is why I'm using **TYPE**.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key. Pay particular attention to the `delims` and `tokens` options. I'm also not sure what you mean, are you saying that `type` does not work line by line, first to last?

Comment: Without knowing what your `dir` output is, what the content of the `.txt` file is or the content of the individual files in the `links` tree, you'd probably be looking for something more like this: ```@CD /D "%UsersProfile%\Desktop\script" && For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "links" /B /S') Do @For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%H In ('Type "test.txt"') Do @For /F "Delims=:" %%I In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /NLIC:"%%H" "%%G"') Do @"links2.exe" "%%G" "%%I" && Echo %%H```

Comment: Or possibly a little bit better given we don't have any information, ```@CD /D "%UsersProfile%\Desktop\script" && For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "links" /B /S') Do @For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%H In ('Type "test.txt"') Do @For /F "Delims=:" %%I In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /NLIC:"%%H" "%%G"') Do @("links2.exe" "%%G" "%%~I") && Echo "%%~H"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
... for /f "delims=" %%t in ...
```

Stands out. Your code will select the first token by default, using the default delimiters (<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>) hence "Coupon". Using "delims=" selects the entire line for `%%t`